# C++ example for video compression

Tags: c++, video, compression, h.264, codec

Here is my problem.
I have a server and client application.
The server component gets the video stream from a digital video camera. Then server dumps to the network for client to see the stream.
Because I have save the video on the server for later replay with each frame time stamped, it uses too much hard disk space as well as too much bandwidth on the network traffic for a given HD video, so I have to compressed video using h.264 or other open source compression standard.

I am able to get a handle of each frame of raw video stream from a camera, the question is: Are there any simple C/C++ video codec library out there that I can easily encode each frame, save and decode each frame on the fly? Perhaps give me some examples on how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: An h.264 encoder (or decoder) is *not* going to be simple. It can be simple to *use*, but internally, the code is almost inevitably quite complex because h.264 itself is quite complex. One possible starting point would be the [h.264 reference implementation](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/download/). Another obvious possibility would be a packaged CODEC like [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: You might be able to try and dig through VLC to see about leveraging its dependencies.  http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc.html  there's a section, "Third party libraries used by VLC".

Answer (score 0):

x264 is a great free* video encoder. It has a ver easy to use API, once you have each video frame in YUV240p. Or, libavcodec/libavformat may be better if you what to experiment with other codecs and containers.

*You usage may still require a commercial license from x264, or mpegLA